# JavaScript and Classic ASP: Trimming variable down to first five digits

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have the following on a checkout page and need to only pass the first five digits of the `sSTFormZip` variable. There's something strange going on behind the scenes that causes the five-digit Zip Code field to be appended with four digits that aren't correct for returning customers. (It's a long story, but the short of it is that they were repurposing the last four digits to identify the county for those Zips that span over more than one county.)

```
<input id="STZIP" type=TEXT name="ST_ZIP" maxlength="<%= oRFF.max_length %>" 
 value="<%= sSTFormZip %>" onChange="setRecalcFlag();">
```

How can I populate the field with 92708 when the database is storing something like 92708-1234?

After seeing one of the suggestions below, I added this above the input, but it did not impact the field:

```
<script>
    sSTFormZip = sSTFormZip.substring(0, 5);
</script>
<input id="STZIP" type=TEXT name="ST_ZIP" maxlength="<%= oRFF.max_length %>" 
 value="<%= sSTFormZip %>" onChange="setRecalcFlag();">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take the first five characters of the `sSTFormZIP` variable, then the VBScript [`Mid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3.aspx) function is the one you're after:

```
Mid(sSTFormZIP, 1, 5)
```

Should return the first five characters. The parameters to `Mid` are:

1. The string that you want to extract a part of
2. The index (1 based) of the first character you want to extract
3. The number of characters you want to extract

You could also use the [`Left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk3xcs8k.aspx) function:

```
Left(sSTFormZIP, 5)
```

Which will take the left-most five characters of `sSTFormZIP` and return them.

Comment: The trouble I'm running into is how to insert JavaScript inside the ASP tags:
    value="<%= sSTFormZip %>

Comment: Why would you want to do that when the answer Rob gave negates gthe need for the javascript

Comment: @user3120861, Your question doesn't make any reference to JavaScript other than in the title, the tags and the fact that you're triggering a function in the onChange event. Your question, as it stands, has nothing to do with JavaScript, so it's quite unclear what your comment has to do with the question and answer given?

Answer (score 2):

```
<%
dim s
sArray = Split(sSTFormZip,"-")
%>

<input id="STZIP" type=TEXT name="ST_ZIP" maxlength="<%= oRFF.max_length %>" 
value="<%= sArray(0) %>" onChange="setRecalcFlag();">
```